# Migrating from TFS to Git, convert TFS branches to Git branches or to Git repositories?

Tags: git, tfs, migration

I'm trying to migrate a big `TFS` repository to `Git`. The `TFS` structure looks like this:

```
$/TfsProject
+ MainProject
+ MainProject-Release1 (Branch of MainProject)
+ MainProject-Release2 (Branch of MainProject)
+ MainProject-Release3 (Branch of MainProject)
```

I was wondering if i should migrate the TFS branch to seperate Git repositories or to one big Git repository with branches?

The `MainProject` is about `300 MB` in size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First you are going to end up with performance issues unless you remove all of the binaries from source. You should use NuGet for dependencies and some form of CDN for images and other assets.

Other than that you can just use Git-TF to do a full fidelity clone and push to the new repo. 350mb is big but not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think MRHinsh has a point, you should try to use NuGet for dependencies and pushing your images to a CDN is a great idea too.

But to answer your question, Both work. I have worked in teams that prefer a separate repository for each release, while some other teams prefer to use Branches.

If your are moving from a TFS branching method then you will have less of a learning curve for the team if you stick with branches in Git, however sometimes it is wise to move to a completely new way of doing things (repositories) as it help to reduce bad habits coming over from the old way of doing it.

My preference is to do it with repositories, but that is because when we converted I wanted to loose the old bad habits.